# How to send a Protonmail with c++?

Tags: c++, email, smtp

my question is how to send a protonmail with c++ code? I know that c++ is a bad language for that, but I need it done with c++. I don't know which port or even which library to use, there is way to low support and documentation for that.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is not a bad language, if you want to send emails via C++ I suggest you find an SMTP library, here's one:

https://github.com/embeddedmz/mailclient-cpp

There are many email protocols that services use for receiving and sending mails, SMTP is the most common one for outgoing emails, for any programming language it's not hard finding a library for such protocols.